# How would you concisely express 'the range of dates in which something is expected to happen'?

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests, concision

I need a conside expression for "the range of dates in which someone expects something might happen". For instance,

> I called John to ask him for a more precise period in which he estimated he might host his party.

I am looking for a noun or a phrase that expresses the meaning of the quotation more elegantly.

Comment: I think for something informal, you can just ask, "John, when are you thinking of having your party?"  What you'd likely get back is answer that will satisfy your question, such as, "Oh, sometime next month."  If there is a need to have a more specific response than you would need to modify your question accordingly, "John, I'm leaving for Europe on June 15th.  Do you plan to have your party before then?"  If it is a true date range that you need, then you can ask, "Can you give me a date range for when I can expect to see that project completed?"  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for:

> [***timeframe***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/time%20frame) *: a period of time especially with respect to some action or project*

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would probably just say "I called John to ask him when he might host his party". If you don't think "when" by itself gets at the whole meaning you're looking for, I would also say "I called John to ask him when exactly he might host his party" or "I called John to ask him for a more precise timeframe for his party". Your sentence is grammatical but a little wordy.

(My only reference here is being a native speaker of English.)